# Crystal reports formula

Tags: c#, windows, forms, crystal-reports

```
if{((tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr1})- tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr3})) > tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr1}))}
then 
{
    ((tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr1}) - tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr3})/tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr1}))*100)    
} 
else  
{
    @add
}
```

//please provide solution for this error

Comment: can you please post the error?

Answer (score 1):

I think the code should be like this:

```
if((tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr1})- tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr3})) > tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr1}))
then 
{
    ((tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr1}) - tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr3})/tonumber({BudgetTemplateField.Expr1}))*100)    
} 
else  
{
    @add
}
```

i think it will work.reply.